# In java, How can i print the following pattern

Tags: java

This is the pattern and i cannot figure how to do print it in java

```
1 1
12 3
123 6
1234 10
12345 15
```

I've tried this:

```
class IOP {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        int sum =0;
        for (int i = 1; i<=5;i++) {
            for (int j =1;j<=i;j++) {
                sum = sum+j;
                System.out.print(j + " " );
            }
            System.out.print(sum);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint.  You need one loop that prints out the numbers from 1 to n and their sum, and another loop to increase n by 1.

Comment: You are very close. Notice that `sum` needs to be reset for each row, or incremented only once per row by row counter (`i`). Also it looks like you don't want to print space after each number but only before sum.

Comment: I've edited your question so that the data and code are correctly formatted and easier to read, but in the future you'll want to do this yourself as well as provide more detail on the problem with your code.  Please go through the [tour], the [help], the [Stackoverflow Advanced Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void print(int total) {
    for (int i = 1, sum = 0; i <= total; i++) {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, i).forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.println(" " + (sum += i));
    }
}
```

---

**Output**

```
1 1
12 3
123 6
1234 10
12345 15
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move sum to first loop body, so that it will reset after each loop.

Secondly add some padding to the sum result.

```
for (int i = 1; i<=5;i++) {
   int sum = 0; // reset sum before each iteration
   for (int j =1;j<=i;j++) {
       sum = sum + j; // sum all numbers
       System.out.print(j + " "); // print each number
   }
   System.out.print("|  " +sum); // print the sum, with a padding, to separate results
   System.out.println(); // add a new line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i<=5;i++) {
            int sum =0;
            for (int j =1;j<=i;j++) {
                 sum = sum+j;
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            System.out.print(" "+sum);

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**O/p**

```
1 1
12 3
123 6
1234 10
12345 15
```